# Fourier tranform of the Euclidean norm

Tags: analysis, fourier-transform

where can I find the Fourier transform of the power of the Euclidean norm?, that is:

$$\mathcal{F}[\|x\|^{p}](\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}\exp(-2\pi i \langle\omega, x\rangle) \|x\|^{p} dx$$

Thank you!

Comment: If $p$ is an even integer, this can be expressed as the Fourier transform of a polynomial and thus as some derivative of the $\delta$-function. For other $p$, maybe the method discussed in section 4 of http://faculty.missouri.edu/~grafakosl/preprints/RadFT34.pdf can help. To apply this you would need to know the answer for $d = 1$ (to get other odd $d$) and $2$ (to get other even $d$).

Answer (score 1):

In vol. 1, Chap.II, Sec.3.3 of the book *Generalized functions* by Gelfand-Shilov you will find the formula

$$ F\bigl[\Vert x\Vert^\lambda\bigr](\omega)=2^{\lambda+d}\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{\lambda+d}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(-\frac{\lambda}{2}\right)} \Vert\omega\Vert^{-\lambda-d}, $$

or all $\lambda\neq -d,-d-2,\dotsc $, where, for $\lambda>0$ you should think of $\Vert\omega\Vert^{-\lambda-d}$ as a generalized function in the precise sense described in Chap.I. Sec. 3.9 op.cit.